# disable a block in django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I want to disable a block in development and use it in deployment in google apps in python development. What changes do i need to make in template or main script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got the middleware [django.core.content_processors.debug](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-debug) then you can just do this in your template:

```
{% block mydebugonly %}
    {% if debug %}
    <p>Something that will only appear if the DEBUG setting is True.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The debug middleware also requires that you put the IP address of the testing machines in the ``INTERNAL_IPS`` setting, usually INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',) will do the trick.  I seem to always forget to do this when putting debug blocks in my code.